# Change default user relationship on Drupal Commerce customer profile

Tags: commerce

I need to change the relationship of Drupal commerce module "Customer". I wish I no longer use the relationship user ID, but the id of another custom entity. We find the example of using this relationship to the url admin/trade/customer profiles-Part "User Information" => "Owned by ...", this is where I will wish in the end that the address is not connected to a user but a separate entity that I created myself.

Is this possible? I looked a little deeper into the Customer module, but I am afraid of losing myself in a bad voice, I need your advice and some ideas :)

Thank you in advance